# Cannot remove Material-ui TextField margin

Tags: css, reactjs, input, material-ui, styled-components

Using styled-components and inline styling, I am unable to remove the padding around material-ui's TextField component. Any ideas? That inline width works though (styled-component width did not work).

Example:

[image: example image]

Code:

```
const StyledSelect = styled(SelectField)`
  margin:0;
  input {
    margin:0;
  }
`;
const StyledText = styled(TextField) `
  margin:0;
  input {
    margin:0;
  }
`;
return (
  <div>
    <StyledText
      type="number"
      floatingLabelText={this.props.title}
      onChange={this.handleAmtChange}
      value={this.state.amount}
      style={{ width: '100px', margin: '0px', input: { margin: 0 } }}
      min={0}
    />
    <StyledSelect
      floatingLabelText="Unit"
      onChange={this.handleUnitChange}
      value={this.state.unit}
      style={{ width: '100px', margin: '0px' }}
    >
      <MenuItem 
        value={0} 
        primaryText={"In"} 
      />
    </StyledSelect>
  </div>
);
```

#### Update

I was originally using material-ui 0.X but updated to `1.0.0-beta.26`. The problem is a bit better but still extremely noticeable. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Do you pass the className in the SelectField and TextField Components? See here: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-components Otherwise the margin wil never pass down to your component.

Comment: These components are made by material-ui, I believe they pass the class name property down

Comment: They actually do: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/src/TextField/TextField.js

But i think the problem might be, that the inner components get passed  passed a "...ClassName" as className. So i do think, your styled component only styles the FormComponent of MaterialUI, but not the elements within that. Might that be the cause? Try a border padding to see what is being affected exactly.

Comment: What version of Material-UI?

Comment: have you tried `<div className={"some-global-class ${this.props.className}"} />;`? according to the doc, this should combine the classes https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#existing-css

Comment: I updated my material-ui version which changes the nature of the problem a bit. Any new ideas? Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

For my particular problem and code I added `style={{marginTop: '-20px'}}` to the TextField:

```
<TextField style={{marginTop: '-20px'}}/>
```

So, for your example, I think you need to add `marginTop: '-20px'` to your "StyledText" `style={{` section. Play with the negative marginTop value until you get it right. To find out what you need exactly, in google chrome right-click your area of interest and go to "Inspect" to see the code for it. Make your negative `marginTop` value large enough to negate whatever positive value is messing it up.

Where I first mentioned this: https://github.com/TeamWertarbyte/material-ui-chip-input/issues/91#issuecomment-394498826